# Authentication / Client Validation / How to check if input is a number?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, isnumeric

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to add your phone number")]     
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

I want to allow numbers only and display error message if it's not a number. I also want to limit it to only 10 digits. How exactly can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You are asking multiple questions: showing an error message is not related to checking the user input. You are also expected to search on your own and show what code or strategy you have come up with. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know, i just showed how my current code looks like , and then i explained what i wanted to add. I did some google research but came up with confusing stuff like "regex", didn't really understand formatting or anything so i decided to ask here.

Comment: Use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute.